# Centering my site in html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I was wondering if i could do something similiar to this site (http://www.viralnova.com/hasnt-bathed-60-years-gallery/?mb=sk&Skyid=815). This site has a background then on top of the background their is a clump of content. As you slide the page back and forth the content stays centered, unless you slide the page to the very left. At this point the page stops adjusting and just stays put on the left. I was wondering if their was something to put this effect on my site. Should i make my site content inside a specific div then tell that div to center?

Sorry if my question is confusing. 
-thanks

Comment: you want to leave some space in both sides of your website ? like margin ?

Comment: Example website just times out for me.

Comment: if you want margin and wrap contents like that, use CSS margin: 0px auto; padding: 0px 10px;

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap your content like following code

```
<div class="wraper">
    <div class="content"></div>
</div>
```

set the width to the wrapper and `margin` `auto` to left and right of the wraper

```
.wraper {
    display:block;
    width:200px; <-- define a width
    height: 100px;
    margin: 10px auto; <-- set margin left and right to auto
    background: yellow;
}
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ehqvjse9/)

Comment: One question, this did work and it centered the buttons and inputs that i had. The only problem is that when i do this the tabs for my site just stack on top of each other.

Comment: may be the class name is same to something used in your tabs. or you have to give enough width to the wrapper element